# Making A Dynamically Created Excel Report Downloadable

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have 2 blocks of code, if someone could help me put them together I would get the functionality I am looking for. The first block of code downloads a gridview to excel using the download dialog I am looking for:

```
Public Overloads Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(ByVal control As Control)
    ' Verifies that the control is rendered 
End Sub

Private Sub ExportToExcel(ByVal filename As String, ByVal gv As GridView, ByVal numOfCol As Integer)
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", filename))
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    Dim sw As New StringWriter()
    Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

    gv.AllowPaging = False
    gv.DataBind()

    'Change the Header Row back to white color 
    gv.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF")

    For i As Integer = 0 To numOfCol - 1
        gv.HeaderRow.Cells(i).Style.Add("background-color", "blue")
        gv.HeaderRow.Cells(i).Style.Add("color", "#FFFFFF")

    Next

    For i As Integer = 0 To gv.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim row As GridViewRow = gv.Rows(i)

        'Change Color back to white 
        row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White

        For j As Integer = 0 To numOfCol - 1
            row.Cells(j).Style.Add("text-align", "center")
        Next


        'Apply text style to each Row 
        row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode")

        'Apply style to Individual Cells of Alternating Row 
        If i Mod 2 <> 0 Then

            For j As Integer = 0 To numOfCol - 1
                row.Cells(j).Style.Add("background-color", "#CCFFFF")
                row.Cells(j).Style.Add("text-align", "center")
                '#C2D69B
                'row.Cells(j).Style.Add("font-size", "12pt")
            Next

        End If
    Next
    gv.RenderControl(hw)

    'style to format numbers to string 
    Dim style As String = "<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>"
    Response.Write(style)
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

The second block of code is a sample report I am wish to be downloaded. So instead of downloading a gridview I want this function to accept a worksheet object.

Comment to Frank's suggestions...
Frank thanks for your help this almost works for me. The problem is the code crashes if I dont have a dummy file called test.xls in my root folder. And when I put it there it then loads 2 workbooks test.xls[1] and Book 2 which test.xls is a blank workbook and Book 2 is the correct dymanically created report. I dont want to save this file in th eroot folder if I dont have too, I want the users to simply open of download it to their client. The code im using after the woorkbook is created is...
Dim fn As String = "RptCrd_ " & "BUNDLE" & ".xls"
        Dim eio As String = "~/ContentDisposition/" & fn

```
    Dim exData As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(eio))
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fn))
    Response.ContentType = "application/x-msexcel"
    Response.BinaryWrite(exData)
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
    releaseObject(xlApp)
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
```

Comment: I need the function to accept a workbook object NOT a worksheet instead of a gridview

Comment: Perhaps I did not understand your question. I thought you want to send the data to Excel. This is what led me down the Response Header path.

Comment: I was just using a saved spreadsheet as a test to show how to formulate a response header that the browser would interpret as a MS Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Could I read the bytes of a workbook object and name the workbook instead of reading the bytes of a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to add the proper content type and header to your Response so the browser knows you want to handle the download with Excel. You'd likely put this after the Response.Write(style); call.

Try Googling for MS Excel mime type, and also how to add a properly formatted Header and Content Type to your Response.

I just threw some code together to spit out a download to the browser so that it can handle it as an Excel spreadsheet. This should give you an example of how to format the Response Headers.

This just reads in an existing spreadsheet then feeds it to the response stream. This just demonstrates how to formulate a Response Header.

```
  byte[] excelData = File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("test.xls"));

  Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.xls");
  Response.ContentType = "application/x-msexcel";
  Response.BinaryWrite(excelData);
```

Comment: I very lost on this one could really use some detailed help if you have time. If I simply take out my line of code that reads xlWorksheet.SaveAs(filename) it will let me save the file anywhere but the dialog that comes up for that is asking me if I want to save as "Book 3" which is kinda a wierd message for users to see.

Comment: I edited my comment to include some simple code that forms a Response Header that tells the browser that the data coming in is for Excel to handle.

Comment: Frank thanks for your help this almost works for me. Please read the edited question

Comment: I see a problem with my code is using this approach I am going to have to save the workbook in the root folder in order for the bytes to get read. So I need to add   xlWorkBook.SaveAs(fn) before  Dim exData As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(eio))

Comment: But I do not want to save the file on the server. Should I just put a line of code in to delete it after I read the bytes in?

Comment: There is likely a way to convert the data into a byte[] array (without saving it) that can be used in the Response by calling BinaryWrite(). I've used ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes() before to convert strings to a byte[] array. It's food for thought =)